# Why is my ASUS P5SQL PRO not detecting my OCZ Vertex II 60 gb SSD?

Tags: installation, ssd, sata

Why is my ASUS P5SQL PRO not detecting my OCZ Vertex II SSD?

I've unplugged all drives. I've systematically moved the SSD to SATA headers 1-6. I've also set the BIOS to use AHCI mode instead of IDE.  The BIOS lists only "harddrive" in the boot device list - no details or type or name. The system acts like it can't find the drive because the BIOS POST messages get to:

> Auto Detect Sata [insert header number]...

And here it just hangs (for whatever I had set the IDE drive timeout to). I was patient and waited long enough for the Windows 7 install to get to the point of asking me what drive to install Windows on, but no drives are listed.

During boot, I can put a finger on the SSD and feel it working mechanically so it doesn't seem completely defective. I've researched this and found a few links that suggested the precise troubleshooting process I just explained, but I'm having no luck with it.

This link is my issue verbatim, but their resolution is not working for me:
http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?83755-How-to-configure-ASUS-P5QL-PRO-and-OCZ-Vertex2-60GB

This link is for a different OCZ SSD, but it amounts to the same tasks. Still it hasn't helped.
http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/277228-32-installed-wont-detect

I'm a programmer and hardware isn't my main forte. I can do this, but I'm running out of things to try.

I flashed the BIOS to the latest 1004 version.

What else can I do?

Comment: I don't think you should be able to "feel" an SSD working, except maybe heat?  Have you tried a different power plug?  A different SATA cable?  Does the drive get detected in another system?

Comment: I've got the computer out in a test bed setup. All I mean is I can feel the drive subtley whirling or vibrating when I put my finger on it. I've tried several Sata cables and all of my PSU's Sata power connectors. Same results each time. I don't have another system to test the drive in, but a friend gave it to me after he got some new parts (drive wasn't used long). It worked for him, but he had a different motherboard.